# Understanding the difference between 2 questions.

Tags: abstract-algebra, ideals, maximal-and-prime-ideals, unique-factorization-domains, quadratic-integer-rings

Here is the question I want to answer:

Let $R$ be the quadratic integer ring $\mathbb Z[\sqrt{-5}]$ and define the ideals $I_2 = (2, 1 + \sqrt{-5}), I_3 = (3, 2 + \sqrt{-5}),$ and $I_3^{'} = (3, 2 - \sqrt{-5}).$

$(a)$ Prove that $2, 3, 1 + \sqrt{-5}$ and $1 - \sqrt{-5}$ are irreducibles in $R,$ no two of which are associate in $R,$ and that $6 = 2 . 3 = (1 + \sqrt{-5}).(1 - \sqrt{-5})$ are two distinct factorizations of $6$ into irreducibles in $R.$

$(b)$ Prove that $I_2, I_3,$ and $I_3^{'}$ are prime ideals in $R.$ [One approach: for $I_3,$ observe that $R/I_3 \cong (R/(3))/(I_3/(3))$ by the Third Isomorphism Theorem for Rings. Show that $R/(3)$ has $9$ elements, $I_3/(3)$ has $3$ elements, and that  $R/I_3 \cong \mathbb Z/ 3 \mathbb Z$ as an additive abelian group. Conclude that $I_3$ is a maximal (hence prime) ideal and that $R/I_3 \cong \mathbb Z/ 3 \mathbb Z$ as rings.]

$(c)$ Show that the factorization in $(a)$ imply the equality of the ideal $(6) = (2)(3)$ and $(6) = (1 + \sqrt{-5})(1 - \sqrt{-5})$. Show that these two ideal factorizations give the same factorization of the ideal $(6)$ as the product of prime ideals (cf. Exercise $5$ in section $2$)

**My question is:**

What is the difference between answering the last part in $(a)$ and $(c)$? could anyone explain this to me please?

Prove that $6 = 2 . 3 = (1 + \sqrt{-5}).(1 - \sqrt{-5})$ are two distinct factorizations of $6$ into irreducibles in $R.$

$(c)$ Show that the factorization in $(a)$ imply the equality of the ideal $(6) = (2)(3)$ and $(6) = (1 + \sqrt{-5})(1 - \sqrt{-5})$. Show that these two ideal factorizations give the same factorization of the ideal $(6)$ as the product of prime ideals (cf. Exercise $5$ in section $2$).

Comment: In part a, you show that $6$ **does not** have unique factorization into primes in $\Bbb{Z}[\sqrt{-5}]$.  In part c, you show that $(6)$ **does** have unique factorization into prime ideals in $\Bbb{Z}[\sqrt{-5}]$ -- the apparently different factorizations aren't factorizations into primes, so aren't complete and when you complete the factorization down to prime ideals, you get the same factorization both ways.  That is, the ring does not have unique factorization, but its ideals do.

Comment: So what is the answer to the first part of $(c)$ @EricTowers?

Comment: You need to factor the ideal $(2)$ into a product of powers of the prime ideals $I_2$, $I_3$, and $I_3'$.  Similarly factor $(3)$, $(1+\sqrt{-5})$, and $(1- \sqrt{-5})$.  (Of course, once you know either complete factorization of $(6)$ and the factorization of either factor of the other factorization, you know the factorization of the fourth of these four ideals.)